# When to use method insert (xml)

Tags: theme

I would like to understand when (and why) should I use `<action method="insert">...</action>` instead of using `<block type="... />`.

Example: move cart sidebar from left to right column :

1/

```
<reference name="left">
 <action method="unsetChild">
  <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
 </action>
</reference>
```

2.1/

```
<reference name="right">
 <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" tempalte="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

2.2/

```
<reference name="right">
 <action method="insert">
  <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
 </action>
</reference>
```

2.1 or 2.2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you should use the insert action when you want to move a block that was already added to the layout. For the example you gave it should be something like this:

```
<reference name="left">
  <action method="unsetChild">
    <name>cart_sidebar</name>
  </action>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
 <action method="insert">
  <block>cart_sidebar</block>
 </action>
</reference>
```

If you use:

```
<reference name="right">
  <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar"   template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

I think this would unnecessary create a new instance of the block class when the layout is generated.